# MATLAB: build confidence region

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, statistics, confidence-interval, data-fitting

I am trying to perform anomaly detection of images in a patch-wise manner in MATLAB.
 For each patch in the image, I extract a `6x1` feature vector `g`, where each component is an indicator.

I have to use the confidence region `cr`, defined by the snippet below (I couldn't post the image), built on all the feature vectors of the normal patches and use it for testing new patches.

```html
<a href="https://www.codecogs.com/eqnedit.php?latex=\dpi{100}&space;\mathcal{R}_{\gamma}=\lbrace\phi\in\mathbb{R}^6:&space;\sqrt{(\phi&space;-&space;\overline{\bf{g}})'\Sigma^{-1}(\phi-\overline{\bf{g}})}\leq\gamma\rbrace&space;\\\\&space;\text{where&space;$\overline{\bf{g}},$\Sigma$&space;are&space;the&space;average&space;and&space;the&space;sample&space;covariance&space;of&space;g}" target="_blank"><img src="https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?\dpi{100}&space;\mathcal{R}_{\gamma}=\lbrace\phi\in\mathbb{R}^6:&space;\sqrt{(\phi&space;-&space;\overline{\bf{g}})'\Sigma^{-1}(\phi-\overline{\bf{g}})}\leq\gamma\rbrace&space;\\\\&space;\text{where&space;$\overline{\bf{g}},$\Sigma$&space;are&space;the&space;average&space;and&space;the&space;sample&space;covariance&space;of&space;g}" title="\mathcal{R}_{\gamma}=\lbrace\phi\in\mathbb{R}^6: \sqrt{(\phi - \overline{\bf{g}})'\Sigma^{-1}(\phi-\overline{\bf{g}})}\leq\gamma\rbrace \\\\ \text{where $\overline{\bf{g}},$\Sigma$ are the average and the sample covariance of g}" /></a>
```

Informally, I want to check if a test feature vector falls inside the confidence region and so label the patch as `normal`, otherwise `anomalous`.

I am struggling to understand how to build a confidence region in R6 using MATLAB. I have tried using [bootci](https://it.mathworks.com/help/stats/bootci.html?searchHighlight=bootci&s_tid=doc_srchtitle), but doing so `cr` becomes a `2x6x6` matrix and I don't understand the meaning of the third dimension. Any help or suggestion is appreciated! 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is to classify a 6-D vector φ, just apply the formula in your snippet. Assuming that `sigmaInv` is the inverse of the sample covariance and that φ and **g_bar** are column vectors i.e. `size(phi) = size(g_bar) = (6,1)` then

```
s = (phi-g_bar)'*sigmaInv*(phi-g_bar) % note the ' after the first () = transpose
```

is a scalar and `sqrt(s) <= gamma` means normal, the opposite means anomalous. (Taking the square root assumes that the sample covariance is positive-definite).
If `phi` and `g_bar` are row vectors, then the formula should have the transpose after the second parenthesis:

```
s = (phi-g_bar)*sigmaInv*(phi-g_bar)' %  apostrophe now after second ()
```

Hope this helps